# Архитектура базы данных для мессенджера

Tags: mysql

Опишите, пожалуйста, архитектуру базы данных для мессенджера
Как я представляю, должно быть две таблицы — первая хранит пользователей, вторая хранит переписки по `id` пользователей.

Comment: Зависит от требований месенджера. Может нужна таблица для друзей. Может нужна таблица для стикеров. Может нужна таблица для фото. Продолжать можно долго

Comment: Да, кстати, а как хранить фотографии в таблице?

Comment: @Schepalin обычно хранят только путь к ним или вообще только название файла - формируя путь к ним автоматически. Сами изображения сохраняются либо на жестком диске, либо в каком-нибудь хранилище (S3, Swift и т.п.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В простейшем случае вы действительно можете воспользоваться двумя таблицами, пользователей `users` и сообщений `messages`, которые могут содержать следующие поля (помимо этих полей могут быть добавлены дополнительные)

```
users
-----
id         - идентификатор пользователя
name       - имя пользователя
...

messages
--------
id         - идентификатор сообщения
to_id      - внешний ключ для связи с таблицей users (сообщение адресовано)
from_id    - внешний ключ для связи с таблицей users (сообщение отправлено)
content    - содержимое сообщения
created_at - время создания сообщения
updated_at - время редактирования сообщения
...
```

Однако, на практике объем таблицы `messages` растет очень быстро и когда она достигает объема порядка несколько сотен мегабайт, даже к индексированной таблице запросы могут быть медленными. Одним из способов оптимизации схемы является вынос всей текстовой информации сообщения в отдельную таблицу `contents` по связи один к одному

```
messages
--------
id         - идентификатор сообщения
to_id      - внешний ключ для связи с таблицей users (сообщение адресовано)
from_id    - внешний ключ для связи с таблицей users (сообщение отправлено)
content_id - внешний ключ для таблицы contents (содержимое сообщения)
created_at - время создания сообщения
updated_at - время редактирования сообщения
...

contents
--------
id         - идентификатор сообщения
content    - содержимое сообщения
```

В результате размер таблицы `messages` растет очень медленно, запросы к ней выполняются быстро, даже с учетом того, что вам приходится извлекать содержимое из таблицы `contents`.

Comment: Спасибо! Так и сделал, это как раз тот ответ, который мне и нужен был

Comment: @cheops извините, но вынос абсолютно бесполезный, в данном конкретном случае нет смысла выносить messages  в отдельную таблицу, и размер таблицы тоже не имеет значения. вы просто получаете лишний джойн, хотя  сообщение практически всегда используется со всеми атрибутами, включая id, to, from, created, а updated не нужен, если нет возможности редактировать сообщение

Comment: @strangeqargo, вы работали с такой таблицей на MySQL размером по меньшей мере 1Gb? Ускорение, как правило, на лицо (даже с учетом индексации), когда вместо 1Gb таблицы вы сортируете записи таблицы в 30Мб. Кроме того, тут не очень разумно использовать JOIN, гораздо быстрее получится, если вы воспользуетесь дополнительным запросом IN. Я бы не стал приводить пример, если бы не осуществлял такой рефакторинг на практике. Просто заложить такую архитектуру в начале проекта проще, чем когда будет накоплен 1Gb данных.

Comment: работал, замедление на > терабайтных значениях, но не по первичным ключам. да и при таких размерах лучше на шардинг закладываться. а в предложенном варианте придется узнавать id для фильтрации, а потом уже вытаскивать сообщение. овероптимизация, с дополнительным запросом

Comment: Загнать терабайт в MySQL довольно проблематично (особенно если весь диапазон используется). MyISAM сдохнет, а InnoDB начинает серьезно тормозить, если она не полностью в оперативной памяти. Однако, когда проблемы со скоростью случаются, приведенный выше прием выручает и это не овероптимизация, это в общем довольно распространенный прием. Спорить не буду, тем более SO слава богу, слабо подходит для споров.

Comment: InnoDB прекрасно справляется, я вас уверяю. Да, памяти нужно много, чтобы индексы укладывались. Но приведенный выше прием не поможет, 1:1 это всегда 1:1, незачем вытаскивать данные

Comment: Проблема InnoDB, что она хранит данные и индексы в едином табличном пространстве - вы не можете отдельно кэшировать индексы и данные. Если у вас на сервере 128Гб - это максимум, что вы загоните в оперативную память. Другая проблема InnoDB, что она очень старая и кэширование в ней реализовано в обход операционной системы. В общем, при больших объемах лучше ориентироваться на что-то другое, как вы сами и указали, а при небольших объемах данный прием здорово выручает, так как даже в оперативной памяти вам в большинстве запросов (не во всех) придется лопать меньше данных.

Comment: Черт! Как всегда будет противоположное мнение... и вот думай теперь снова ))))